# OnCard or OffCard encryption?

Tags: security, encryption, data-storage, javacard

Because of security reason I should store encrypted data on Java card,
so the question is should I encrypt data with Offcard application and send it to Java card or send pure data to Java card and let Java card encrypt it by itself?

Anyway, I want to know the best way o store data on Java card and what is the best sequence diagram in order to consider security on data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry if my previous (deleted) comment sounded a bit negative. Asking the right question on the right site is of vital importance for getting a good answer though. Please describe your use case and post the question to security.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: That's ok, anyway I got my answer. Hope not to post these kind of questions anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it depends what you call the off-card application, and whether you consider it trusted (or to which extent you consider it trusted).

In a system involving a card application, a mobile phone application, and a back-end server, usually the server and the card application are trusted, anything inbetween isn't (which means communication has to be done ciphered). The card will want to authenticate any incoming data before processing it. In that case the mobile application is not very much trusted, for various reasons, including the shortcomings of mobile OS's security. You need to elaborate a bit more on your use case. What are the attacks you wish to prevent against, and what part of your system do you trust ?

Anyway to answer your question, the private data managed by the card application does not need to be encrypted before being stored, because the storage can be considered safe.

Comment: Thanks, so I think the way is having private key on card in order to encrypt data just for transferring, and storing data on card not encrypted because of capacity...

Comment: Private keys should never be used to encrypt data, only to decrypt data. Key management and trust establishment are tricky but *should* be defined if you want to create a secure protocol.

Comment: You are right, encryption is with public key, sorry for my fault